# BI Publisher Version Control?

Tags: svn, version-control, bi-publisher

I'm trying to find out how to save my data in BI publisher in version control through SVN checkout if possible.

Is "Export XLIFF" what I'm looking for? 
How do I import it?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend archiving your BI Publisher object(s). 
Catalog > [locate object] > More > Download.
To import it back into BIP, navigate to the destination folder, then click More > Upload.

Please read [this Oracle resource](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/e22257/manage_obj_bi_pub_cat.htm#BIPUG259) for the file extensions of BIP objects:

Use [this Oracle resource](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e22259/webservices.htm#BIPDV002) to access the web services information available for BIP. You can certainly perform Upload and Download functions via web service.

I'm not sure though, how you would use SVN to interact with the web services.